# write easy accessable function

Tags: functions

I want to run an external command by typing `:runMyCommand` (just run a shellcommand). I thought I'd put the shell command execution into a function, so I can call it with `:call runMyCommand`, but I want to get rid of the `:call`.

Is this possible and if yes, how? (I guess something like this was already asked, but in my opinion this issue is really hard to search for)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:h :command` will put you on the right track.

It can be as simple as

```
command! RunMyCommand call RunMyCommand()
```

Or much more complex if you want to support arguments, range...

Comment: This is exactly what I was searching for (but not knowing how this is called in vim) :+1:

Comment: @D.BenKnoble You're right. I've copy-pasted OP's code and I forgot along the way about command restrictions. I fix my answer.